# Segmentation fault: 11 - Xcode 10

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode10

> 2. While type-checking statement at RangeText="{
>          playlistNames = []
>          let requestLibrary = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Library")
>
>    ```
>    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Playlist")
>    request.sortDescriptors = [playlistSortDescriptor]
>
>    playlists = try? context.fetch(request) as NSArray!
>    print("Playlist Count - ",playlists.count)
>
>
>    let librarys:NSArray! = try? context.fetch(requestLibrary) as NSArray!
>    for library in librarys{
>        let libraryName = (library as AnyObject).value(forKey: "library") as! String
>        playlistNames += [libraryName]
>    }
>
>    for playlist in playlists{
>        let playlistName = (playlist as AnyObject).value(forKey: "playlistName") as! String
>        if playlistName == "Library" {
>            playlistNames.insert(playlistName, at: 0)
>        }else {
>            playlistNames += [playlistName]
>        }
>    }
>    ```
>
>    }"
> 3. While type-checking expression at RangeText="playlists = try? context.fetch(request) as NSArray!" error: Segmentation fault: 11

Here is the code:

```
 func refreshPlaylists(){
    playlistNames = []
    let requestLibrary = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Library")

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Playlist")
    request.sortDescriptors = [playlistSortDescriptor]

    playlists = try? context.fetch(request) as NSArray!
    print("Playlist Count - ",playlists.count)


    let librarys:NSArray! = try? context.fetch(requestLibrary) as NSArray!
    for library in librarys{
        let libraryName = (library as AnyObject).value(forKey: "library") as! String
        playlistNames += [libraryName]
    }

    for playlist in playlists{
        let playlistName = (playlist as AnyObject).value(forKey: "playlistName") as! String
        if playlistName == "Library" {
            playlistNames.insert(playlistName, at: 0)
        }else {
            playlistNames += [playlistName]
        }
    }
}
```

It works before i updated to Xcode 10. Any idea ?

Comment: I'm not clear exactly what's segfaulting - it's not your app at runtime? It's XCode, or the Swift compiler?

Comment: @Rup I try to compile and run but it shows me this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such type as `NSArray!` and in any case there was never any reason for you to cast to it. Delete `as NSArray!` throughout. Use Swift types.