# Segmentation fault: 11 Xcode 10

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segmentation-fault

I recently upgraded my Xcode to 10, the previous version of my app is working fine but in Xcode 10 it shows an error.

> error: Segmentation fault: 11

[image: Error]

Here's the log:

> 1. While emitting SIL for 'showPatientInfo(liveNumber:)' at /Users/ranahaani/Desktop/Cleaniq pro/Cleaniq
>      pro/Controller/AdminPanelViewController.swift:451:5
> 2. While silgen emitFunction SIL function "@$S11Cleaniq_pro24AdminPanelViewControllerC15showPatientInfo10liveNumberys5Int32V_tF".
>      for 'showPatientInfo(liveNumber:)' at /Users/ranahaani/Desktop/Cleaniq
>      pro/Cleaniq pro/Controller/AdminPanelViewController.swift:451:5
> 3. While silgen closureexpr SIL function "@$S11Cleaniq_pro24AdminPanelViewControllerC15showPatientInfo10liveNumberys5Int32V_tFySo16FIRQuerySnapshotCSg_s5Error_pSgtcfU_".
>      for expression at [/Users/ranahaani/Desktop/Cleaniq pro/Cleaniq
>      pro/Controller/AdminPanelViewController.swift:455:226 - line:507:13]
>      RangeText=

```
"{ (DocumentSnapshot, err) in
                    if let err = err {
                        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                    } else {
                        for document in DocumentSnapshot!.documents {
                            self.patientName = (document.get("patientName") as? String!)!
                            let patientNumber = document.get("patientPNumber") as? String
                            let patientGender = document.get("patientGender") as? String
                            let patientStatus = document.get("patientStatus") as? String
                            let pToken = document.get("tokens")as? String
                            let patientAge = document.get("patientAge")as? String
                            self.docKey = document.documentID
                            self.documentReference = document.reference
                            self.customerName.text = self.patientName
                            self.patientNumber.text = patientNumber
                            self.tokenNumber.text = pToken
                            self.Processing.text = patientStatus
                            //txtPStatus.setText(patientStatus)
                            self.Age.text = "Age -\(patientAge ?? "Age")"

                            if ((patientGender?.caseInsensitiveCompare("Male")) == ComparisonResult.orderedSame){
                                self.imageViewPatient.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "boy")
                            }else if ((patientGender?.caseInsensitiveCompare("Female")) == ComparisonResult.orderedSame){
                                self.imageViewPatient.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "girl")
                            }
                            else if patientGender?.caseInsensitiveCompare("Other") == ComparisonResult.orderedSame{
                                self.imageViewPatient.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "girl")
                            }


                            if (patientStatus?.caseInsensitiveCompare("Booked")) == (ComparisonResult.orderedSame){
                                SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "Please wait....")
                                self.documentReference.updateData(["patientStatus" : "Processing"], completion: { (err) in
                                    if (err != nil){print(err?.localizedDescription ?? "Error in Patient Status")}
                                    else{
                                        self.showPatientInfo(liveNumber: liveNumber)
                                        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                                    }
                                })
                            }
                            else if (patientStatus?.caseInsensitiveCompare("Cancelled")) == (ComparisonResult.orderedSame){
                                self.callNextPatient();
                                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

                            }
                            if (patientStatus?.caseInsensitiveCompare("Processing")) == (ComparisonResult.orderedSame){
                                self.Processing.fadeTransition(0.4)
                                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }"
```

It used to work before I updated to Xcode 10. Any idea ?

Comment: Have you already read https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/103947 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52377015/segmentation-fault-11-xcode-10